# RegisterIdConvention in RavenDB 2.x async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ravendb

I'm trying to leverage RavenDB's DocumentConvention API to automatically set an incremental ID on my domain objects.

I have this working perfectly using this line of code on the IDocumentStore:

```
DocumentStore.Conventions.RegisterIdConvention<User>
    ((dbname, commands, user) => "users/" + commands.NextIdentityFor("users"));
```

This creates sequential IDs of my user objects with *"users/1"*, *"users/2"*, etc. whenever I store a new User object without an ID already set.

However, I want to do this for an Async document session, but haven't been able to find any documentation on how get the "Next Identity" from the session when calling *RegisterAsyncIdConvention()*...

```
docStore.Conventions.RegisterAsyncIdConvention<User>
    ((dbname, commands, user) => "users/" + commands.NextIdentityFor("users"));
```

... doesn't compile because *NextIdentityFor* is not available on the *IAsyncDatabaseCommands* interface.

Can anyone give me any hints at all? Has anyone tried to do this yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you describe with the sequential IDs is already the default.  You don't have to do anything special with conventions to get this behavior.

It works for async sessions too - but originally it did not actually set the value of the id property when first stored.  This was discussed on the mailing list in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/LXxhNiEhZTQ/EDz6i89wRa0J).  I believe the [pull request](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/pull/247) made it into the latest unstable build, but I have not verified.

**Update**  (from comments)

By default, the convention is to use the pluralized form of the type name.  If the type name is a single word, it is returned in lower-case.  If it has multiple words, then the casing is preserved.

Consider:

```
var user = new User { Name = "Joe" };
session.Store(user);

var fooBar = new FooBar { Name = "Whatever" };
session.Store(fooBar);

Debug.WriteLine(user.Id);
Debug.WriteLine(fooBar.Id);
```

With no changes to conventions, this will output:

```
users/1
FooBars/1
```

If you want to change this convention, you simply supply a new lambda function:

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = type => type.Name.ToLower();
```

Run the same code as before, and you'll now get:

```
user/1
foobar/1
```

But maybe you want to keep the pluralization and just want all lowercase?

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = type =>
              DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(type).ToLower();
```

Outputs:

```
users/1
foobars/1
```

Maybe you just want PascalCase always?

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = type =>
{
    var s = DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(type);
    return s.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + s.Substring(1);
};
```

Outputs:

```
Users/1
FooBars/1
```

Or perhasps camelCase always?

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = type =>
{
    var s = DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(type);
    return s.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + s.Substring(1);
};
```

Outputs:

```
users/1
fooBars/1
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, indeed it is the default behaviour, but I'd like to have all my document and collection names in lowercase. It's just a matter of taste, but is there a way of doing this? Currently storing a _User_ object will create a _Users_ collection with an ID of _Users/1_. I'd prefer to have _users/1_.